# How do I add an extra dictionary/ custom dictionary for fiction writing in Open Office?

Tags: dictionary, openoffice

[image: picture of OpenOffice with right click menu open to adding new word to dictionary standard.dic]

So as I add custom definition using my story, it's just adding them to Standard. Is there some way to split off custom words just for my fic?